# Getting IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: while reading csv file from local to databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I'm using  PySpark version 3.5.0. I'm trying to read a csv file from my local system to databricks & would like to store it in pyspark data frame.

So I wrote following code
`df=spark.read.csv("D:\Pyspark on databricks\original.csv")` and I got following error
`IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: D:%5CPyspark%20on%20databricks%5Coriginal.csv`

Can you please help me to resolve the issue?